# Does the graph have a Hamiltonian circuit or a Hamiltonian path?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonicity

[image: Graph that is to be assessed]

Certain necessary conditions for a Hamiltonian circuit such as the graph being 2-connected, having zero pendants are met. Dirac's and Ore's theorem provide sufficient conditions, which are not satisfied by this graph, so it may possibly not be a Hamiltonian circuit. But as they are not necessary conditions, we can't yet conclude that this is not a Hamiltonian circuit. To me it seems that this graph does not contain a Hamiltonian circuit, as the entrances to the inner subgraphs have 2-degree vertices as their neighbours, then those edges must be traversed, similarly if we start from the inside of the subgraph, same situation occurs. But I cant put together a coherent formal argument for it.

In case of Hamiltonian path, the same thing happens, and I also cannot write it out properly. What way should I go about to argue in detail that this graph does not contain a Hamiltonian path or a circuit?

An additional query is, in this graph must only 2-degree vertices be the end vertieces of a path? Why?

Comment: Hint: There is a 2-colouring of the vertices of the graph, and there are an odd number of vertices.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That proves that the graph does not have a Hamiltonian Circuit, as the first vertex and last vertex of the path will be the same color, which is a contradiction. How about proving that Hamiltonian Paths also dont exist?

Comment: The vertices of the minority colour cannot be the end point of a Hamiltonian path.

Comment: If a Graph that is 2-colored with majority vertices having Red, and minority vertices having Blue color, has a Hamilton path, then said path will either begin with a Red or a Blue vertex, but Blue cannot be an endpoint as it will lead to leftover Red vertex or consecutive Red vertices. If Red is chosen to be first then last vertex would also be Red, I am confused how this case leads to the Hamiltonian path not existing.

Comment: The four outer corner vertices are all coloured blue, therefore cannot be an end point of a Hamiltonian path. They are of degree two, so all their edges become part of the Hamiltonian path. But that forms a loop that is shorter than what is needed for a Hamiltonian circuit/path.

Comment: hmm, I had noticed that before commenting, and thought just saying that it would be shorter would require me to enumerate all the paths. I thought I was missing something more along the lines of a contradiction reached in the case of blue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

More detailed hints than in the comments.

Why there is no Hamiltonian path in this graph.

For convenience, let the vertices of degree 2 be red. Let the other vertices be blue.

First, note that the red vertices in each path cannot be neighbors, since they form an independent set.

It follows that if a Hamiltonian path starts with a blue vertex, then since there are $8$ red vertices, this path must also end with a blue vertex. Question: Where is the location of vertex $p$?

Let a Hamiltonian path start from a red vertex.
In this case it is from the inner square (why?).
By the same reasoning, there should be two blue vertices at the end of this path, and the last one is $p$.

Now find the first vertex on the Hamiltonian path from the outer square.
It is preceded by a vertex from the small square.
So they are both blue (why?).

**Addition.**

I will try to answer the OP's question from the comment below.

Recall that since the graph is bipartite and the parts have 8 and 9 elements, a Hamiltonian cycle can only start in the larger part. By the way, here are its parts: $aceg\ ojqm$; $bdfh\ ikln\ p$.

If a Hamiltonian cycle starts from a red vertex, then this red vertex is a larger part. The red vertices of the larger part all lie in a inner square. This is the answer to the first question.

Now to the second question.
If we started our path in the inner square and set a goal of going around all the vertices of the graph, then somewhere along the way we will be in the outer square for the first time. Isn't that right?

Comment: If the path starts with a blue vertex, B_R_R_R_R_R_R_R_R_, then in each dash atleast 1 B would be present. There would be atleast 2 consecutive Bs, as the inner subgraph can be accessed only via an edge that has two non-2degree vertices as end points. Also there can be only 2 consecutive Bs and no more, as doing so will end the path at one of the corner vertices or skip said corner vertices. Therefore If it begins with Blue, then it must end with Blue. Is my thought process valid?

Comment: It is not clear to me why It must start in the inner or outer square, as a path will either miss a corner or the centre, or it will get stuck at a inner corner. Also the last line is not clear to me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, your reasoning in the first comment is correct.